# Использование java приложений в Linux

Tags: jar, eclipse, linux, java, ubuntu

Как можно в Ubuntu Linux java программы (`.jar`) сделать `.deb` пакетом или просто программой?

Comment: Для каких целей? .deb, и просто программа - это немножко разные вещи

Comment: Пользоваться написанной на Джаве программой.

Comment: Видимо, человек считает, что если получиться сделать deb, то для этого придется jar файл сделать "программой".
@Romanzi - одно могу сказать - java придется тащить с Вашей программой или просто ставить в зависимости к пакету.

Answer (score 4):

Несмотря на весь сарказм комментаторов вопрос имеет право на жизнь. От того что пакет станет executable он не перестанет требовать JVM/JRE, просто jar будет упакован в некий легкий загрузчик, который будет "на лету" распаковываться в jar и подаваться на вход к JRE. Аналогичные упаковщики есть для среды Windows ([и их много](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=convert+jar+exe)).

Для Ubuntu рекомендую изучить [следующую ссылку](http://mojo.codehaus.org/deb-maven-plugin/using-deb.html), где рассказано и показано как упаковать исполняемый JAR в пакет DEB

Comment: Мой вопрос вовсе не содержал в себе сарказма, мне просто хотелось узнать больше деталей, для чего это потребовалось сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно только запустить программу .jar, это можно сделать командой

java -jar name.jar